Do angels in their glory/spirit state cook and eat? Are there truly 'heavenly' cooked food that angels eat just like humans do? Do they thirst/hunger?
I am aware that angels can 'step down' from their full angelic glory into the form of humans (Gen.19:1-3, etc). Lot did not see angels in their full angelic state; he saw men like himself (that's what I understand) and realised that these were not normal humans but angels who 'stepped down' from their glory.  I know that people have entertained angels (in human likeness) Heb.13:2).
However, Ps.78:25 compared with Jn.6:32 is a puzzle for me. They do not explicitly say that angels eat food in their realm. Does 'angels' food' mean they are food meant to be eaten by angels?
